# Docker + Virtual Box = VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed docker. During installation, it complained that you can't have two virtualization environments, and that it would make docker the primary one. I said: "OK."

Now, I need to go back to enabling virtualbox. I uninstalled Docker, hoping it would put things back the way they were, but: no joy.

How do I re-enable virtualization for VirtualBox now that docker is gone?

Note: Virtualization bit is set / enabled on the chip.

OS: Win10 Enterprise.

Comment: Just re-install VirtualBox.

Comment: I did a repair installation. Will now completely uninstall, reboot, say a prayer to the Windows API gods, and try again...

Comment: Uninstalled virtualbox, rebooted, re-installed. No joy.

Comment: What if I need _both_ VirtualBox and Docker working on Win10?

Comment: You cannot run them both at the same time. Docker on Windows is (essentially) creating a Linux VM to handle the kernel name spaces that docker relies on (and which is not available in Windows 10 as of 1 year, 9 months ago when I posted this question). Hyper-V and Docker are not compatible with each other. You have to pick one.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Virtualbox will get upset and not run if Microsoft Hyper-V is enabled.

Here's the solution:

1. Open command prompt as administrator

   - search for 'command'
   - right-click then select 'run as administrator'
2. paste the following command:

   ```
   dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
   ```
3. Then reboot.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Installed docker to play around with but messed up my VirtualBoxes. Make sure to run as administrator

Comment: Yes. Docker REQUIRES Hyper-V to work in the first place.

Comment: You might need to disable Virtualisation Based Security too. https://superuser.com/a/1415967/155706

Comment: After reboot, you need to disable Hyper-V in programs and features as described here - https://superuser.com/a/1477432/1137687

Comment: ```
Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
```

Answer (score 12):

To complete @DrDamnit answer, it is also possible to disable Microsoft Hyper-V from the menu.

1. Search for "**Turn Windows features on**" on the start menu

[image: Turn Windows features on and off]

2. Disable Hyper-V

[image: Disabele Hyper-V]

3. Reboot your computer

Voilà